# Python KeyError in format() using strings

Tags: python, format

I tried to use the `format()` function in python and it gives me the `KeyError`. Don't get why. I looked up some websites using the `format()` function in combination with strings and I was convinced that I was doing it right, obviously I am not.

```
servoid     = "test1"
parameter   = "test2"
value       = "test3"

#message = '{"servoid":"{}","parameter":"{}","value":"{}"}'.format(servoid,parameter,value) # <-- key error
message = '{"servoid":"'+servoid+'","parameter":"'+parameter+'","value":"'+value+'"}'      # <-- works fine

print(message)
```

Output of the fine working line =

```
{"servoid":"test1","parameter":"test2","value":"test3"}
```

Output of the not so fine working line

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\sknippels\Documents\machine_software\mqtt_test\TestEAL_EFC.py", line 126, in <module>
    message = '{"servoid":"{}","parameter":"{}","value":"{}"}'.format(servoid,parameter,value) # <-- key error
KeyError: '"servoid"'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are placing ```''``` at wrong place .. It must be like this ```message = {'"servoid":{},"parameter":{},"value":{}'.format(servoid,parameter,value)}```

Comment: You need to escape the opening and closing `{` `}`. `message = '{{"servoid":"{}", "parameter":"{}", "value": "{}"}}'.format(servoid, parameter, value)`

Comment: @Manvi, this will make `message` a `set`, not `str`

Comment: The one of Buran yields correct results, thnx. The other missed the extra set of {} needed for json format

Comment: @bask185, if you constructing JSON, this is wrong way to go all together and it makes the question XY problem. Use `json` module. Create a dict and then dump it in JSON

Comment: I have the module already working for decoding them, not yet for encoding. I will take a look into it. Python is already vague enough for me as it is

Comment: `json` module from standard library is dealing with JSON, both for encoding and decoding. Don't reinvent the wheel

Answer (score 3):

`format()` is looking for curly brackets `{}` to insert the values. You need to escape it with additional brackets

```
message = '{{"servoid":"{}","parameter":"{}","value":"{}"}}'.format(servoid, parameter, value)
```

It will work with `f-string` as well

```
message = f'{{"servoid":"{servoid}","parameter":"{parameter}","value":"{value}"}}'
```

**Edit**:

Since your goal is to create json you should use the `json` library instead of building it manually

```
import json

data = {'servoid': servoid, 'parameter': parameter, 'value': value}
message = json.dumps(data)
```